# What is the equivalent to iloc for dask dataframe?

Tags: python, dask

I have a situation where I need to index a dask dataframe by location.  I see that there is not an `.iloc` method available.  Is there an alternative?  Or am I required to use label-based indexing?

For example, I would like to

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = dd.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame({k:np.random.random(10) for k in ['a', 'b']}), npartitions=2)
inds = [1, 4, 6, 8]
df.iloc[inds]
```

Is this not possible with dask?  (e.g., Perhaps a positional location is not well-defined?)  In this case, what can I do if I only know the positional indices (not labels) of the values I need to access?

Answer (score 6):

Positional indexing is not available for dask dataframe, nor is it likely to be available in the near future.

Comment: Why? This is a bummer.