# How to perform positional indexing in Python Dask dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

I've been working through the Dask Concurrent.futures [documentation](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/examples-tutorials.html), and I'm having some trouble with the (outdated) [Random Forest example](http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2016/04/20/dask-distributed-part-5). Specifically, the use of positional indexing to slice the dask dataframe into test/train splits:

```
train = dfs[:-1]
test = dfs[-1]
```

And to no avail I've also tried:

```
train = dfs.loc[:-1]
test = dfs.loc[-1]
```

which gives me the error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2524             try:
-> 2525                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2526             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-fff88783d91d> in <module>()
      7 test = dfs.loc[-1]
      8 
----> 9 estimators = c.map(fit, train)
     10 progress(estimators, complete=False)

/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/distributed/client.py in map(self, func, *iterables, **kwargs)
   1243             raise ValueError("Only use allow_other_workers= if using workers=")
   1244 
-> 1245         iterables = list(zip(*zip(*iterables)))
   1246         if isinstance(key, list):
   1247             keys = key

/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2284 
   2285             # error is raised from pandas
-> 2286             meta = self._meta[_extract_meta(key)]
   2287             dsk = dict(((name, i), (operator.getitem, (self._name, i), key))
   2288                        for i in range(self.npartitions))

/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2137             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
   2138         else:
-> 2139             return self._getitem_column(key)
   2140 
   2141     def _getitem_column(self, key):

/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _getitem_column(self, key)
   2144         # get column
   2145         if self.columns.is_unique:
-> 2146             return self._get_item_cache(key)
   2147 
   2148         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality

/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _get_item_cache(self, item)
   1840         res = cache.get(item)
   1841         if res is None:
-> 1842             values = self._data.get(item)
   1843             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
   1844             cache[item] = res

/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in get(self, item, fastpath)
   3841 
   3842             if not isna(item):
-> 3843                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
   3844             else:
   3845                 indexer = np.arange(len(self.items))[isna(self.items)]

/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2525                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2526             except KeyError:
-> 2527                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2528 
   2529         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0
```

What is the proper way to use positional indexing in Dask, and what would be the correct way to slice the dataframe into test/train splits in the Random Forest example?

Similar unanswered question: [What is the equivalent to iloc for dask dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46773660/what-is-the-equivalent-to-iloc-for-dask-dataframe)

EDIT:
Creating the original list of futures pointing to Pandas dataframes failed:

```
from distributed import Executor, s3
e = Executor('52.91.1.177:8786')

dfs = s3.read_csv('dask-data/nyc-taxi/2015',
                  parse_dates=['tpep_pickup_datetime',
                               'tpep_dropoff_datetime'],
                  collection=False)
dfs = e.compute(dfs)
progress(dfs)
```

throwing the error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-25aea53688ef> in <module>()
----> 1 from distributed import s3
      2 
      3 dfs = s3.read_csv('dask-data/nyc-taxi/2015', 
      4                   parse_dates=['tpep_pickup_datetime', 
      5                                'tpep_dropoff_datetime'],

ImportError: cannot import name 's3'
```

Misunderstanding that this was a dask dataframe rather than a list of futures pointing to Pandas dataframes, I tried:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

dfs = dd.read_csv('s3://dask-data/nyc-taxi/2015/*.csv', 
                 parse_dates=['tpep_pickup_datetime', 'tpep_dropoff_datetime'],
                 storage_options={'anon': True})
dfs = c.persist(dfs)
progress(dfs)
```

which is what is now causing the indexing problem I mentioned previously. How should I modify this to read from the S3 bucket to a list of futures pointing to Pandas dataframes as described in the blog post?

Answer (score 2):

I recomend reading documentation, not blogposts.  Old blogposts are likely to go stale quickly.  Documentation is kept up to date.

In this code in that blogpost `dfs` is a list of futures to dataframes, not a dask dataframe.

```
train = dfs[:-1]
test = dfs[-1]
```

If you're looking to do a train-test-split then I recommend the [random_split](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.random_split) method.

Positional indexing is not supported, nor is it likely to be in the near-to-moderate future.

Value-based indexing (`.loc`) is supported if you have a well-formed index and divisions, see [divisions docs](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-design.html#partitions)

Comment: In your blogpost, the code for creating dfs now fails:
`ImportError: cannot import name 's3'`
How would one create this list of futures to dataframes now?

Comment: Here, I made a stack overflow question for you:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48792589/how-do-i-convert-a-list-of-pandas-futures-to-a-dask-dataframe/48792590#48792590

Comment: if one wants to create a 0-based index when the Dask dataframe is created, how would one do this?

Comment: This looks like a separate question.  Can I ask you to ask this yourself this time, perhaps with a clear example for others like what was done in the question above?

Comment: My apologies @MRocklin, I will modify my original question here to be more clear, the stack overflow question you posted did not provide an answer to the s3 error that I receive when I attempt to create the list of futures pointing to Pandas dataframes.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48796323/how-do-i-convert-from-a-dask-dataframe-to-a-list-of-futures/48796324#48796324 .  It would be useful to create simple questions like this in the future.  Generally I don't recommend working from old blogposts.

Comment: as mentioned in the question, this comes directly from your [documentation](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/examples-tutorials.html) (see Ad Hoc Distributed Random Forests).