# How do I convert a list of Pandas futures to a Dask Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have a list of Dask futures that point to Pandas dataframes:

```
from dask.dataframe import Client
client = Client()

import pandas
futures = client.map(pd.read_csv, filenames)
```

How do I convert these to a Dask dataframe?

*note, I know that `dask.dataframe.read_csv` exists, I'm just using `pd.read_csv` as an example*

Answer (score 3):

You probably want [dask.dataframe.from_delayed](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.from_delayed)

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.from_delayed(futures)
```

See the docstring for additional options.