# How do I convert from a dask dataframe to a list of futures?

Tags: dask

I have a dask dataframe like the following:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv('s3://...')
```

How do I get a list of futures from this dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the the [.to_delayed](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.Series.to_delayed) method to convert from a dask dataframe to a list of [dask.delayed](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/delayed.html) objects

```
L = df.to_delayed()
```

You can then convert these delayed objects into dask futures using the `client.compute` method.

```
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client()

futures = client.compute(L)
```